# How Kohana implement sessions saved to database?

Tags: kohana, kohana-3.2

the source code hands Session_Cookie and Session_Native class but the Session_Database, 
here the config file

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct script access.');

    return array(
        'database'  =>  array(
            'database' => array(
            'name' => 'blog_session_cookie',
            'encrypted' => TRUE,
            'lifetime' => 43200,
            'group' => 'default',
            'table' => 'sessions',
            'columns' => array(
                'session_id'  => 'session_id',
                'last_active' => 'last_active',
                'contents'    => 'contents'
            ),
            'gc' => 500,
        ),
        ),
    );
```

usage

```
    $session = Session::Instance("Database");
    $session->set('username', 'far');
```

great, its added a  column in database, amusing! How the core do that? 
thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It's handled by `Session_Database` class in `Database` module

See the source: https://github.com/kohana/database/blob/3.2/master/classes/kohana/session/database.php

Answer (score 0):

To implement database session mechanism there is [`Auth_ORM`](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/api/Auth_ORM) class in Kohana 3.2.